# Display days in calendar depending on the month

Tags: javascript, function, calendar, logic

I'm working on a calendar. Stuck at the place where you want to display the number of days, depending on the month. Months I switch and the number of days remains unchanged. I do not understand how to do this. I will be very grateful for the detailed explanation. A link to the calendar `(http://codepen.io/Ho4ka/pen/PpOgpe)`

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of days in the given year and month in JavaScript:

```
new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```

For January, `month` = 1, for February, `month` = 2, and so on.

Ex:

```
new Date(2017, 2, 0).getDate();
=> 27
```

Comment: Could you write me a solution with comments? Maybe it suddenly. I'm brand new and yet to me it is difficult not understand how.